Show In Tree not working in Pimcore 11.4.3 version
When clicking the 'show in tree' icon in PIM version 11.4.3, the folder structure does not display as expected. Instead, the action fails to retrieve and present the hierarchical folder layout within the interface. This functionality should enable users to see the folder structure clearly, allowing for easy navigation and access to the required objects or categories. Investigating and resolving this issue will ensure proper visibility of folder hierarchies when the 'show in tree' feature is utilized

This is not a question, is it? Maybe you should post a bug report at the appropriate place. This is not the place for bug reports.
